# Google Script "Exceeded Maximum Execution Time" / Google Cal Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-docs

So, based on lots of internet sleuthing I've managed to cobble together a script that uses a Google Sheet to create all-day calendar entries. There's probably ~450 total rows of content that I would like to create events for, but every time I run the script it never gets to the end, and it never creates an EventId (to address duplicates), rather, it gives me an "Exceeded Maximum Execution Time" error.

```
    $ function onOpen() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var entries = [{
name : "Export Events",
functionName : "exportEvents"
}];
sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

function exportEvents() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headerRows = 0;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();
var calId = "evsck12.com_fp4p25esvij964uhmfs51o9ar8@group.calendar.google.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
for (i in data) {
if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
var row = data[i];
var date = new Date(row[0]);  // First column
var title = row[1];           // Second column
var id = row[3];              // Sixth column == eventId
// Check if event already exists, update it if it does
try {
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
}
catch (e) {
  // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
if (!event) {
  var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date).getId();
  row[3] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
}
else {
  event.setTitle(title);
range.setValues(data);
}
debugger;
}


}
```

My questions are these:

- How can I avoid this error? If I split the data into several sheets will that work?
- For the life of me I can't get the eventiD section to populate... I managed to do it on a test sheet but I can't do it anymore... any help would be fantastic!

For reference my sheet is set up as 
Date / Title / eventId

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first a few errors in your code...

1. You update row[3] but forgot to update data with its corresponding row value, I simplified by using only data as variable.
2. you used `row[3]` for third column, it is `row[2]` (now `data[i][2]`)
3. You updated the sheet at a wrong place in the loop

The working code is below (I changed the cal ID to one I own for test purpose... restore yours of course)

As for the time limit, you should proceed by limited batch of events, take a look at the execution transcript to see how long it takes for 1 and multiply...to get a value well below 5 minutes which is the maximum execution time in Google Script.
Then you should keep somewhere the value of the row index (i) and using a time trigger proceed with the next batch starting at this index.

The [documentation on trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) creation will help you and [the scriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties) is the ideal place to keep the index value in a key/value schema. See doc as well.

If you have issues with that don't hesitate to come back with a new question .

```
function exportEvents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 1;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "h22nevo15tm0nojb6ul4hu7ft8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var date = new Date(data[i][0]);  // First column
    var title = data[i][1];           // Second column
    var id = data[i][2];              // third column == eventId
    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
    if (!event) {
      Logger.log(event);
      var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, date);
      data[i][2] = newEvent.getId();  // Update the data array with event ID
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(title);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(data);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```